# Oracle Pivot with value containing &

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

My query is:

```
select * from (
select 
aa_id, abc_metric, abc_value from TABLE1)
PIVOT(
min(abc_value)
FOR abc_metric IN ('Mode (numbers & dates)')
);
```

In abc_metric, I have a value called as `Mode (numbers & dates)` but SQL developer is asking me value of dates.

[image]

How can I make the query work?

Comment: Did you try escaping it with a backslash?

Comment: No, how to do it?

Comment: IF yoy run SET DEFINE OFF before your query SQL Developer will stop thinking & indicates a substitution varaiable and run your query as expected. Run SET DEFINE ON to turn the default behaviour back on.